# Calling a function of erlang file from shell script

Tags: linux, scripting, erlang, ejabberd

I have a file xyz.erl which contains a function fun1.I want want to call it from linux script.Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

You can create *escript* from your file. Follow the [instructions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html)

In brief, you should add call instructions for the shell and erlang to the begginig of you file

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%% -*- erlang -*-
```

Then make file executable.

Then you can call erlang script as conventional script. **Note that you still required Erlang runtime installed to execute script.**

Erlang calls `main/1` function of the script but you can pass function name as an argument to call it

```
main([Fun]) ->
    FunAtom = list_to_atom(Fun),
    ?MODULE:FunAtom().
```